# Do we need both "nature" and "wildlife" tags, and how they should be used?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Yeah, it's that time again.

We have [nature](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature) and [wildlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife). They are mostly consistently applied, but the question is whether we need to differentiate between the two. Both aren't used too much currently to warrant their own tag, and there are situations that will require use of both simultaneously, which feels like overkill.

So, the question is, should we make [nature](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature) the main tag and [wildlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife) its synonym? Or some other arrangement you deem suitable?

Comment: Keep in mind there is an ambiguity between voting for this question being a good question that needs to be asked, and voting up meaning do it vs voting down meaning don't do it.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm waiting for someone to voice an opinion that can be voted on.

Comment: Implemented as voted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know: [nature-and-wildlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature-and-wildlife) with [wildlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife) mapped to it as synonym.

**BOOM BABY!**

Comment: When in doubt merge the names as well as the tags (-:

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of nature isn't wildlife. Waterfalls, volcanoes, tundra, deserts, rainforests, coral reefs, even something like the cherry blossom time in Tokyo might all get tagged nature but not wildlife. So if they are to be synonyms, it should be that if I choose wildlife I get nature and not v.v.

Personally I think they're different - a person asking about polar bear tours or diving with sharks or volunteering at an elephant sanctuary might not tag "nature" -- but since they're both going to be quite small compared to say airports or visas, I can see why they might be merged.

Comment: Actually I just thought of things like zoos and safari parks where you will see wildlife not in nature. So maybe they shouldn't be merged?

Answer (score 1):

I'm indifferent. I think these tags will work well whether merged or separate, unlike some other tags.

Answer (score 0):

Vote **UP** if you think [nature](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature) and [wildlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife) should be merged.

Vote **DOWN** if you think they should be separate.

Comment: Nature can be waterfalls, mountains etc.  Wildlife is animals!

Comment: Come on Mark, you know tag synonyms are not about English synonyms, they're about what's useful to keep together vs more useful to separate. For me on this particular pair of tags it makes no difference either way but that's not to say I don't understand where the proposal is coming from. Diving is not snorkelling either, customs is not immigration, etc etc etc ...

Comment: Hmm, I know, but you can  go to Africa on a safari holiday or a sightseeing holiday, and the two are *very* different...in my books at least.

Comment: That's why I'm indifferent I suppose (-: